# SonarQube XPATH: Validate the data based on the delimiters

Tags: xml, xpath, sonarqube, xpath-1.0

We have a pattern set of file name separated with delimiter, Sometimes Customers put the incorrect naming pattern, to validate it we are using SonarQube, Can we split the data based on delimiter and validate it?

**Correct Pattern:**
1st File:

```
<root><filename>FILE_SALES_Outlet_C2C_CARGO_09092021</filename></root>
```

2nd File

```
<root><filename>FILE_SALES_Inhouse_B2B_WAREHOUSE_10122021</filename></root>
```

Incorrect Pattern:

```
<root><filename>FILE_09092021_SALE_BB_CARGO_Copy</filename></root>

<root><filename>SALES_Business_WAREHOUSE_10122021_v2_File</filename></root>
```

In a single xpath Can I Validate below rules?

1. It should Start with FILE
2. After 1st Delimiter (_) it should be always SALES
3. After 3rd Delimited it should be (C2C/B2B)
4. It should only have 5 delimiters

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not so pretty) XPath-1.0 expression (if the second string should start with 'SALES'):

```
/root/filename[starts-with(.,'FILE') and starts-with(substring-after(.,'_'),'SALES') and (substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(.,'_'),'_'),'_'),'_')='C2C' or substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(.,'_'),'_'),'_'),'_')='B2B') and (string-length(.)-string-length(translate(.,'_',''))=5)]
```

or (if the second string should be 'SALES' only)

```
/root/filename[starts-with(.,'FILE') and substring-before(substring-after(.,'_'),'_')='SALES' and (substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(.,'_'),'_'),'_'),'_')='C2C' or substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(.,'_'),'_'),'_'),'_')='B2B') and (string-length(.)-string-length(translate(.,'_',''))=5)]
```

Both approaches should do the job.